# Using Python to send messages in Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chat

Is it possible to make a Python program that sends messages in a Discord chat every 2 minutes, but without other users being able to see that it is a program?

Comment: What you are looking for is selfbotting, and it is against [discord's TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a bot to send message every two minutes using the below code

```py
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def determine_winner():
  message=#Message to be sent
  channel_id=#Gives the id of channel where to send
  client.get_channel(channel_id).send(message)
```

If you want to send this message in multiple channel. You should get the id of each channel where the message to be sent and store it in database or json file and fetch it at the time of sending the message.
`But self-botting is against discord'sTOS if they found you self-botting they will ban you from discord permanently`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how do they discover bots? What if I change the time between chats every now ans then and I insert a for loop with a lot of different messages to be sent?  Like, do they have bots that trace self-bots or do they ban bots manually?

Comment: Let me explain your question with an example:If you are using ``autotyper for discord`` with different messages with different time and try to gain more coins for more than 2 hours even DankMemer bot in discord detects you are self-botting and bans you from using their commands. Since Dank Memer detects this self-botting i am sure that discord will found you and ban your account if you are using autotyper or something like that for more time